# Codeigniter: How to declare a global variable for a recursive function, and how to return it?

Tags: codeigniter, recursion, scope

I want to use recursion in a model in Codeigniter, and am baffled as to where I should declare the global variable to be used in the recursive function.

I'm trying to show a catalog of products, ordered by their geographical classification. The recursion is needed because the geographical database is a hierarchy tree, where a place can have sons, grandsons, great-grandsons etc (for example: London is the son of England, which is the son of Britain, which is the son of Europe).

At the end of the recursion, I want to return the variable `$arrCatalog`, which will hold all the products. So my other question is how to return that variable in the end?

Here is my code (not tested yet, because I didn't know how to handle the global variable):

```
 class Catalogs_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }



function getCatalog($place_id, $prod_type)
{
    $sql =
        "SELECT id, heb_name, type FROM places p
        INNER JOIN places_relations r ON p.id = r.son
        WHERE father = ?
        ORDER BY sort_name";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $place_id);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $place) {

                $sql2 =
                        "SELECT code, heb_title, price, place_id FROM products
                        INNER JOIN products_places ON prod_code=code
                        WHERE place_id = ? AND prod_type = ?";
                    $query2 = $this->db->query($sql, $place_id, $prod_type);

                    if($query2->num_rows() > 0) {
                            foreach ($query2->result() as $product) {
                                    $arrCatalog[] = $product; // $arrCatalog is the global variable I don't know where to declare and how to return.
                            }

                    $this->getCatalog($place['id'], $prod_type);

                    }

        }
    }

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variable to the current object ($this), then you can pass it around your model or hand it to a controller.

```
class Catalogs_model extends CI_Model {
    public $arrCatalog = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getCatalog($place_id, $prod_type) { 
    $sql = "SELECT ...";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $place_id);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $place) {
            $sql2 = "...";
            $query2 = $this->db->query($sql, $place_id, $prod_type);

            if($query2->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query2->result() as $product) {
                    $this->arrCatalog[] = $product;
                 }
                 $this->getCatalog($place['id'], $prod_type);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Your controller:

```
$this->catalogs_model->getCatalog(2, 'hebBook');
$data['data_rows'] = $this->catalogs_model->arrCatalog;
```

Testing, alter your model like so ....

```
class Catalogs_model extends CI_Model {
    public $arrCatalog = array();
    // add these variables for testing ....
    private $greeting = 'Hello'; // notice this is private?  You cannot access this from your controller but you can from anywhere within the Catalogs_model class.
    public $output = ''; // public 
    public $string = null; // public

    // your existing code ...

    function hello ()
    {
        $this->output = $this->greeting;
    }

    function hello_string ()
    {
        if($this->string)
        {
            $this->output = $this->greeting.' '.$string;
        }
    }
} // end class
```

Now test in your controller

```
$this->catalogs_model->hello(); // runs the hello function which sets the model->output
echo $this->catalogs_model->output;  // echos 'Hello'

echo '<br />'; // just so the output stands apart in your browser.

$this->catalogs_model->string = 'World!';
$this->catalogs_model->hello_string();
echo $this->catalogs_model->output;  // echos Hello World!
```

Comment: thanks, Derek. but now I'm not sure how to call this function from the controller. I thought I'd use `$data['data_rows'] = $this->catalogs_model->getCatalog(2, 'hebBook');` but if you put the return outside of the `getCatalog` function, nothing would be returned. So how do I do it?

Comment: einav, see the bottom of the response for controller code.  It's terse, but the point is this: call the model->function() and you can access any "public" variable directly with model->variable;

Comment: let me see if I get it right: if I declare a public variable under the model, I can access it from anywhere in the model, or from anywhere in the controller, providing I load that model and the function? why, then do I have to return the value of `arrCatalog` (last line in `getCatalog` function)?     
And I've used your code as explained, but still nothing gets returned. don't know how do I even start to debug it...

Comment: Einav, check the altered answer and review the "Testing" section.  I think you need to review the ins-and-outs of PHP Class Properties (see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: Hi Derek. I owe you a follow up.  For some reason, your solution didn't work (the testing did work, though), so I went back to the drawing board, and had a rethink about recursive functions (this helped: [link](http://devzone.zend.com/283/recursion-in-php-tapping-unharnessed-power/)), and found a way to do what I need without using a global variable. I think it's better practice for a recursive function. But thanks for your help! I now know how to use global variables, and it will surely come in handy soon.